# How to show a bottom sheet which remains throughout the app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show a bottom sheet in my app, which remains throughout the app. How can I implement it in main, so that I don't have to go to every page to display it.

The problem is, I can't wrap Scaffold over MaterialApp, so that option is not available for me. And, after my initial route, it goes over to other pages, so i can't show sheet on my initial page.

Here is my code for MyApp->

```
return Consumer<AppLocale>(
      builder: (buildContext, locale, child) {
        /*locale = Provider.of<AppLocale>(context);
        locale.getLocale();*/
        print("The country code is - ${locale.locale.countryCode}");
        return ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => APIData(),
          child: MaterialApp(
            title: 'Board Plus',
            theme: ThemeData(
              fontFamily: 'Nunito Sans',
              brightness: Brightness.dark,
              textTheme: TextTheme(
                displayLarge: headingStyle1,
                displayMedium: headingStyle2,
                displaySmall: headingStyle3,
                headlineMedium: headingStyle4,
                titleLarge: bodyText3,
                bodyLarge: bodyText1,
                bodyMedium: bodyText2,
                labelLarge: buttonTextStyle,
                bodySmall: linkStyle,
              ),
            ),
            //themeMode: _themeMode,
            supportedLocales: L10n.all,
            locale: locale.locale,
            localizationsDelegates: //AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
                [
              AppLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
            ],
            // home: SplashScreen(),
            initialRoute: isViewed == 0 || isViewed == null
                ? 'splash'
                : 'home', //'language',
            navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[MyApp.observer],
            routes: {
              'home': (context) => AuthenticationWrapper(),
              'splash': (context) => SplashScreen(),
              'language': (context) => LanguageSelectionScreen(
                    val: 0,
                  ),
            },
            scaffoldMessengerKey: scaffoldMessengerKey,
            navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: If it is never going to be discarded, why not use a stack instead?